# Can not find bitbake command inside yocto

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I am using Yocto(poky) freescale linux for creating new software. I have compiled my binaries on Poky 1.6 daisy. But to build recipes on this system I can not find bitbake command.

I searched every where on Google but no luck. Can anybody tell me how do i install bitbake in mentioned machine so that I can create rpm package for that machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bitbake` is at `sources/poky/bitbake`. How did you compile poky binaries? [bitbake](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/bitbake)

Comment: Hi @LPs I have compiled my poky binaries directly on my embedded machine using gcc.

Comment: There is something strange. Yocto is a complete solution that can generate u-boot, kernel, DTBs, and RootFS for your target. Is not necessary to compile binaries "by hand". If you downloaded all Yocto layers, you have a complete toolssuite to do the job. Read [THIS](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html). It is a complete and exhaustive guide to quick start working with Yocto.

Comment: Hi @LPs I have readily got the embedded machine with pre installed Poky 1.6 daisy. I have to create my software package in the form of rpm using that machine. For that matter I have compiled my source code using gcc on embedded machine. But now I have to pack my binaries into rpm and that is why I need bitbake installed on my embedded machine. But I can not find bitbake on my embedded machine.

Comment: You have to download/clone the Yocto repo. Then you must create a new layer into Yocto sources and write your recipe to compile your modules and to create your rpm. You have to follow the guide I linked you to do that.

Comment: swapnilmore, @lp has a point. You are trying to put the cart in front of the horse. Typically you wouldn't compile your software on the target itself but rather on the host(cross compilation). This is where yocto/oe can help you. When doing it on the target you are on your own. Nevertheless it can be also done on the target. Don't use bitbake though. Install rpmbuild and use it directly.

Comment: I tried to install rpmbuild on target by compiling source code of rpmbuild. But it requires large number of header files and libraries, which is very time consuming, Is their any repository from where I can download rpmbuild and/or other development packages for embedded machine?

Comment: @SwapnilMore I don't understand why you compile things on the target because Yocto is there to build all that for you. Have you read documentation that explain how to start with the SDK? For the setup, I had to run `./poky/scripts/host-prepare.sh` and then `source ./poky/fsl-setup-poky -m mytargetname` ... then you will be able to run bitbake (from the build directory once you have used `source mybuilddir/SOURCE_THIS`).

Answer (score 18):

To start using `bitbake` you need to source the "oe-init-build-env" script located into poky/ directory. So you should do something like this:

```
$ cd /path/to/poky
$ source ./oe-init-build-env
$ bitbake <recipe>
```

Hope this helps.